# get file path of a zipped folder cross-zip

Tags: node.js, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using cross-zip node module to zip a directory. This works great when I run this locally , I see the folder. The code looks like this

`var zip = require('cross-zip');`

`zip.zip('./directory', 'zip-folder-name', function(){})`

But when I run this on bitbucket pipeline I don't see the zipped folder. I am assuming this has to do with the path but cant seem to figure out what am I missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cross-zip has dependency with Dot net framework and the image that is used in Bitbucket pipeline may not support that. Either we need to explicitly add the framework or switch to "archiver" - https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver

Archiver works well with node image on Bitbucket pipeline